# Silence ambiguous reversed operator warning in gcc13

Tags: c++, gcc

I have some 3rd party code I can't modify

GCC13 says

```
warning: C++20 says that these are ambiguous, even though the second is reversed
```

On clang I can do

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wambiguous-reversed-operator"
```

But on gcc13 I can't figure out the pragma that silences the warning

```
// Some example that triggers the warning
template <typename>
struct S {
  friend bool operator==(S&&, const S&) { return true; }
  friend bool operator!=(S&&, const S&) { return true; }
};

using U = S<int>;
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
// #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wambiguous-reversed-operator" #<- works fine in clang
bool b = U{} == U{};
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8h1fP4xW8

Comment: Always post complete code here in the question iteself instead of just providing a link to it so that we don't have to click/follow another link to see the question which could've been directly placed here on stackoverflow.

Comment: It is very odd for those operators to take rvalue references.

Comment: How about adding a compiler flag for C++17, if you have C++20 incompatible code that you can't modify?

Comment: Is this code in a header file?  (Presumably, it is, if it's a template)

Comment: yeah its in a header file, the example code was kinda a work bench to test the pragmas available to gcc

Comment: Ok.  Maybe bracket the #include to turn off _all_ warnings then (if there is one).  Make that conditional for testing.

Comment: Not sure how to turn of all warnings using a pragma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That warning does not have an associated command line option in gcc.

It is being issued as a "[pedwarn](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DiagnosticsGuidelines)":

> pedwarn is for code that is accepted by GCC but it should be rejected
> or diagnosed according to the current standard, or it conflicts with
> the standard (either the default or the one selected by -std=).

possibly gcc does not give you the option to silence it because the standard is asking for a diagnostic here.

You can only choose to make it an error or a warning. I guess you will not be able to compile this code with `-Werror`.

The relevant bit of gcc source code: https://codebrowser.dev/gcc/gcc/cp/call.cc.html#12724

(note the lack of test for a specific warning enabled surrounding the issuing code)

Comment: "Can't be done" is probably the right answer. Ended up patching gcc for this project. Sad.